# using old and new value after git update

Tags: git, github-actions, git-diff

I struggle to understand **git diff** and would appreciate your help with this.

#### Scenario:

Given [such a change](https://github.com/terijaki/vcmuellheim/commit/c7157c17fdef773b5d5ddd016d16a87997bb9255) as part of a [workflow](https://github.com/terijaki/vcmuellheim/blob/main/.github/workflows/sams_club.yml), I need to know when a `<seasonTeamId>` changed and then modify other files accordingly. So I need to extract those numbers as variables.

e.g. I need to know that the ID 18452008 changed to 22521759, so I can update another file containing the old ID.

#### Challenge:

There are multiple `<seasonTeamId>` in the xml. One for each of our club's team. And it so happens that an update may include ID updates for one or multiple teams.

---

I am ok with updating the other file using **sed**. But I struggle to detect the change and extract the IDs as variables.

I think **git diff** with **grep** and a regex can achieve this.

```
RegEx : /(?<=<seasonTeamId>).*[0-9](?=<\/seasonTeamId>)/gm
```

git diff is messing with my head and neither documentation nor tutorials are helping

Comment: Would it be simpler working with the raw files? So that you can use `git show @~:path-to-file` for how the file was on the parent of the current commit.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, that the xml includes <seasonTeamId>s of multiple teams. An update to the XML may include more than one updated ID. Any idea how I would got about linking them?

e.g. old-id1, old-id2, new-id1, new-id2

Answer (score 1):

You can actually access *the complete content of your files* with `git` (not just the diff). So, if you somehow know that file `sams/club.xml` was changed by commit `<xyz>`, you can :

- access its content *after* the modification :

  ```
  git show <xyz>:sams/club.xml
  ```
- access its content *before* the modification

  ```
  # <xyz>~ is one way to say "the parent commit of <xyz>"
  git show <xyz>~:sams/club.xml
  ```

From then on, you can get that specific identifier from each file.

for example, using an xml parser :

```
after=$(git show <xyz>:sams/club.xml | xq '.id')
before=$(git show <xyz>~:sams/club.xml | xq '.id')

# do something with $after and/or $before ...
```

---

In the above, `<xyz>` can be replaced by :

- a commit sha : `eacf32d19....` (complete or short version)
- a branch name : `master`, `develop` -- means "the current head of that branch"
- a tag name : `v1.1.2` -- means "the commit pointed by that tag"
- a remote branch name : `origin/master`
- `HEAD` (or `@` alone) -- means "the current active commit"
- etc ...

all gory details can be found in [`git help gitrevisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions)

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, that the xml includes <seasonTeamId>s of multiple teams. An update to the XML may include more than one updated ID. Any idea how I would got about linking them?

e.g. old-id1, old-id2, new-id1, new-id2

Comment: @Terijaki: play with an xml parser, if things get too complicated to be scripted with bash, try using another scripting language (python, nodejs, perl ...)